# How to store queries in SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I manage a mini database and I write procedures for complex transactions and data cleansing. I also do a lot of ad-hoc querying and I save all of my queries in a folder. Is there any way I can save these queries in the database so that some of my peers can review my SQL queries?

In my search, I understand that I can write a procedure for smaller queries too. But I want to know if there is another method to do this?

Comment: Stored procedure is the way to go.

Comment: Your second question is more of a topic for programmers.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Okay. thank you so much brad! also, any specific schema names to store ad hoc query views?

Comment: I've stored ad-hoc queries in a table. Just use a `VARCHAR` or `NVARCHAR` column. You can also include _snippets_, e.g. pieces of text to be substituted before the query is executed. For example, if a user logs in to a website, you could replace occurrences of `{UserId}` in the query with the current user's identification. Similarly, `{DepartmentId}`, `{Role:Manager}`, `{IsAdmin}`, ... . Whatever makes sense in your environment. Implemented properly you are not allowing SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a select statement use a view:

```
CREATE VIEW MyView 
AS
SELECT Columns FROM TABLE
```

Now you can select from that

```
SELECT * FROM MyView
```

and join to it:

```
SELECT * FROM MyView
INNER JOIN SomethingElse 
ON MyView.ID = SomethingElse.ID
```

For scripts that update/delete/insert or do procedural things in order, use a stored procedure instead.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Also, may i ask for any suggestions on how code review can be performed? For example, i share name of view with my peer and what happens if we edit the view ta the same time? which version gets saved?

Comment: Whichever ALTER statement gets executed last will be saved. In other words whoever saved last. How many developers will there be? You might wish to consider using SQL Lock (free in beta from Red Gate) or a Visual Studio database project or some other means to enforce version control if you have many developers. Anyway a code review should involve communication, not overwriting your original code. I also suggest you include comments in your view definitions which contain a change history

Answer (score 0):

You can have queries (views) persisted in the database itself. You can use the [`CREATE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879262.aspx) statement to create views, stored procedures, table value functions etc. which will be accessible through intelisense and show up in the database object tree

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new folder in the Template Browser and add code in new templates.  If you want to share these ACROSS your team using SSMS, you can also do the following:  You DO have to store the code elsewhere, but it can be accessed within SSMS  by all users when set up this way on their machines:

See: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/ssms-shared-sql-templates

Short synopsis:
Store code examples in central location and re-point SQL templates folder on each user machine to the central location, by using `mklink` to create new link to SQL folder under the following location so that the SQL folder will no longer point to it, but to the alternate central location path specified:

```
C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\11.0\Templates
```

To do this open the command prompt and:

- go to user path above and rename SQL folder found under there:  `ren Sql  Sql_Old`
- create symbolic link:  `mklink /D Sql C:\ss\Internal\Code\TSQL\SSMS_Templates`
- if successful, you will see:

  > symbolic link created for Sql <<===>>  path of central code

Afterwards, the template browser will link to the central location and show whatever is in there.